# How do I clean up this R decision tree specifically get rid of all the values under each node

Tags: r, tree

R output is portraying with all values under the nodes, help me clean this up

click here  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUxFf.png

I cannot add the data, however here is the code, I am new at this usually I used SAS and SAS Eminer

`enter code here

`install.packages("party")

```
install.packages("rpart")
install.packages("rattle")
install.packages("rpart.plot")
install.packages("RColorBrewer")




library(rpart)
library(rattle)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RColorBrewer)






fit <- rpart(FPD ~.
              
             
             
             , data = smallfpd
             , method = 'class'
             ,control = rpart.control(minsplit = 10
                                      ,minbucket = 10
                                      ,cp = 0.0001
                                      ,maxdepth = 5))

prp(fit, type=4, extra=101, under=FALSE, faclen=2)
text(fit,pretty)



fit




  
    
A whole bunch of    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)

ordered = c(Store = FALSE, Mon = FALSE, 
    YYYY = FALSE, Cust_State = FALSE, Campaign = FALSE, CUST_TYPE = FALSE, 
    Req_Loan_Amt = FALSE, PaycheckAmt = FALSE, IncomeMonthly = FALSE, 
    Payroll = FALSE, PayPeriod = FALSE, AGE = FALSE, WithdrawReason = FALSE, 
    Fin_Charge = FALSE, APR = FALSE, LoyaltyLevel = FALSE))
```

output for  dput(head(smallfpd))

```
structure(list(Store = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Mon = c(12, 12, 10, 
1, 10, 10), YYYY = c(2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2021, 2021), FPD = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Cust_State = c("OH", "AR", "MN", "CA", "CA", 
"FL"), Campaign = c("II10", "LYSC", "PMSE", "PYCA", "LMCA", "YSSC"
), CUST_TYPE = c("NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "NEW", "NEW"), Req_Loan_Amt = c("$1,850.00", 
"$3,000.00", "$4,000.00", "$2,400.00", "$2,400.00", "$4,000.00"
), PaycheckAmt = c("$9,999,999,999.00", "$190,000.00", "$41,787.00", 
"$26,000.00", "$25,000.00", "$22,146.43"), IncomeMonthly = c("$9,999,999,999.00", 
"$411,666.67", "$41,787.00", "$56,333.33", "$25,000.00", "$47,983.93"
), Payroll = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), PayPeriod = c("M", 
"B", "M", "B", "M", "B"), AGE = c(63, 46, 38, 46, 72, 29), WithdrawReason = c("Void due to active loan in third party", 
"Void due to active loan in third party", "Void due to active loan in third party", 
"Void due to active loan in third party", "Void due to active loan in third party", 
"Void due to active loan in third party"), Fin_Charge = c("$167.98", 
"$273.70", "$610.96", "$225.10", "$478.61", "$375.16"), APR = c(221.9867, 
221.6611, 222.2844, 218.4176, 221.116, 218.4194), LoyaltyLevel = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: No decision tree is provided.

Comment: Read [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: hmm they wouldn't let me attach any ideas?

Comment: I have a link above :) thanks tic toc

Comment: You should include data and the code that produced that plot. Can you post the code you've tried and sample data? Please edit the question with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if `df` is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is a placeholder for the name of your data set.)

Comment: I put output for dput(head(fit, 20))

Comment: An effective `dput(head(my_data))` copies the `structure(...)` [all that structure(and everything enclosed to the last )], and then the data is usable and available.